# open a bundle file which is a react native app on button click in another react native app

Tags: android, react-native

I don't get any reaction on `clicking` a `Touchable button` which has connectivity to `Stack Navigator`
in `parent` app. when i click button it has to load `child component` base file (App or any component)

It has to run within parent like how amazon does.

I shouldn't be using `Intent` or any new coding in `Androidmanifest.xml` in parent app which contains the bundle of child app.

I have tried using the below options

1. https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.65/integration-with-existing-apps

getting error when i create a button and clicking, i couldn't open the base component or any component in the bundled file. i have kept the `bundle file` inside `android/src/main/assets`